# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL..Cannot find any invisible characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong in my code. After googling for several hours I'm not understanding whats wrong in my code(the most frequently suggested answer is check for invisible spaces...which I checked in jsfiddle, but to no avail).

The following is the jquery code.

```
function resetForm() {
     $('input[id="accomodationRemarks"]').val("${trUpdateBean.accomodationRemarks}");
     document.forms[0].reset();
}
```

where the details can be understood by the following struts code

```
    <html:hidden property="accomodationRemarks" name="trUpdateBean" styleId="accomodationRemarks"/>
```

I keep getting Uncaught `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL error` in the developer tools console.

I'm using google chrome in macbook air.

Comment: ${trUpdateBean.accomodationRemarks} - replace this part with a string and check if there is an error.

Comment: Don't look at what's in your source file. Look at what's sent *to the browser*. Odds are pretty high you'll find something like `$('input[id="accomodationRemarks"]').val("When you say "error" what do you mean?");` Note that the `"` inside the text isn't escaped, and thus the code sent *to the browser* has a syntax error.

Comment: @themosquitokiller...i replaced it with something like this ${trUpdateBean.associateName} where associateName is another bean property  and it works...its failing just for this bean property...i guess you got my point...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder...the console shows the following $('input[id="accomodationRemarks"]').val("Marriott Paris Cdg Ariport, Eoissy - Charles De Gaulle 95700 Novotel Bucharest City Centre, 37B Calea Victorei Sector 1, Bucharest, 10061 Hotel Westing Zagred, KRSNJAVOGA 1 - Postal Code:10000");....is there something i can do about this...as there are no quotes inside the code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder...i cannot change the data in val() as it is coming from database...so how to solve this problem. any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: @user3186960: *"i cannot change the data in val() as it is coming from database."* Yes, you can. And you may have to. It may require more work, but you may have to. If the text were really exactly as you've quoted it above, that would work. So my guess is it has line breaks or (and I know you've heard this before) invisible characters in it. You can probably get rid of those with the JSTL `replace` function; search for "JSTL replace" for more information.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder...yeah there are 3 to 4 line breaks as you guessed...now after replacing the line breaks with '.' the syntax error is gone, but  the console says... Uncaught referenceError:resetForm is not defined...does it make any sense to you...?